# UIButton label showing three dots

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I'm setting my button's title with this line of code:

```
self.timerButton.setTitle(String(Int(duration)), for: .normal)
```

The button is as large as 1/3 of the screen, the text size is 60, this was fine in my previous projects, but now with the value of `duration` changes ( from 120 ~ 0 ), the text often shows `...` instead, sometimes even half of a number, what's wrong with this?

Here are the constraints shown in the debugger:

[image]

Comment: Try self.timerButton.sizeToFit()

Comment: Do you use auto layout in your project? Because then it depends how are the constraints set.

Comment: @Deny yes there's constraints

Comment: @Bhumi it worked, but the text is still clipped from the middle sometimes

Comment: @BrightFuture Try to remove leading and trailing constraints for the button and replace them with some centerX constraints if possible. Button should not have a width constraint too. It depends how is your layout.

Comment: @Deny it's kinda tough, the button is actually embedded is a stack view, its constraints are set automatically

Comment: Use `Debug View Hierarchy` and check the size and position of your `Button`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Deny's comment is very helpful, I looked into my constraints and found out I set the button's image size with this method:

```
self.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: (self.frame.height - imageSize) / 2, left: (self.frame.width - imageSize) / 2, bottom: (self.frame.height - imageSize) / 2, right: (self.frame.width - imageSize) / 2)
```

which cause the `titleLabel`'s size to be smaller than it should be, so I changed the above code to this:

```
self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: (self.frame.height - imageSize) / 2, left: (self.frame.width - imageSize) / 2, bottom: (self.frame.height - imageSize) / 2, right: (self.frame.width - imageSize) / 2)
```

then it worked.

TL;DR

> The problem is caused by constraints.

Answer (score 4):

Try this it may help you :

```
self.timerButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Comment: I have also used layoutIfNeeded() with above line of code

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution but setting a width constraint forces the button to not scale down too much, like so:

```
myButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
myButton.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 180).isActive = true
```